# Generar dos letras aleatorias y añadir un guión bajo al final en Bash

Tags: wordpress, bash, shell

Quiero generar dos letras aleatorias y añadir un guion bajo (_), en una variable.

Quiero hacerlo para crear un prefijo aleatorio para la base de datos de Wordpress.

Tiene que ser algo muy simple. Lo he conseguido pero de forma muy chapucera, por lo que quería ver qué se os ocurre a ustedes:

```
RANDOM2=$(tr -dc a-z < /dev/random | head -c 2 | xargs)
SCAPE=_
DB_PREFIX="$RANDOM2""$SCAPE"
```

Funciona: le añade a la variable *DB_PREFIX* contenido como *lx_* o *ue_*; que es básicamente lo que quiero para no usar el prefijo por defecto *wp_* de Wordpress.

**Aunque funciona**, me parece una forma muy cutre.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se me ocurren unas pocas maneras para hacerlo:

Una es instalando `pwdgen`:

```
$ printf "%s_" $(pwgen 2 1)
oi_
```

Otra con `openssh` y `hex`:

```
$ printf "%s_" "$(openssl rand -hex 1)"
```

También puedes utilizar un *class character* en tu sentencia:

```
$ printf "%s_" "$(tr -dc "[:alpha:]" </dev/urandom | head -c 2)"
```

O instalando y usando `apg`:

```
$ printf "%s_" "$(apg -m 2 -x 2 -n 1)"
```

Comment: Me ha servido con la tercera opción aunque quitando lo de [:alpha:] y poniendo a-z, básicamente por que con lo primero me creaba caracteres mayúsculas y minúsculas. No se si se podría sustituir lo de [:alpha:] por otra cosa para que sea solo minúsculas pero en cualquier caso funciona y lo doy como solucionado. De tres lineas paso a una y queda mas limpio obviamente. Gracias.